# Selenium Click is not working on popup messages with IE11 in Windows 7

Tags: selenium-webdriver

OS: Windows 7

Selenium Version:3.10.0

Browser:Internet Explorer 11

Hi,
The tests failing in IE-11 when clicking a button on pop-up message.  Able to find the required element on a web page but click operation is failing.This is an intermittent error as sometimes the clicking will work and the tests will run.

I have set the  ie capabilities also.

```
dCaps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
                dCaps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.
                          INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
                dCaps.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);    
                dCaps.setJavascriptEnabled(false);
                dCaps.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "accept");
                dCaps.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
                dCaps.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
                dCaps.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", true);
                dCaps.setCapability("introduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings", true);
                dCaps.setCapability("ie.ensureCleanSession", true);
                dCaps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_ELEMENT_CACHE_CLEANUP, true);
```

Following is the click method i have used

```
              Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
              actions.moveToElement(webElement);
              actions.click();
              actions.build().perform();
```

Comment: Relevant _HTML_, code trials and error stack trace please.

Comment: Better to write the code so that the people can help you out.

Comment: Consider adding [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problems so you will get much better answers

Comment: We have tried with the other methods like Fluent wait and explicit wait but still unable to perform click operation (inconsistent) on pop-up message. Tried  clicking on the required element by using virtual key word ENTER and Java script er.Written one more method in that first we are performing click operation and rechecking whether the element is present or not in the web page if the element is presented we are re performing the click operation. We didn't find any solution so posted here,Please help with this issue.